# Where is the proof of universality of Rule110 in Stephen Wolfram's book?

Tags: turing-machines, cellular-automata

I have Stephen Wolfram's book A New Kind Of Science. And I want to find the proof of the universality of Rule 110. I couldn't find the clue in the contents page since it only shows 12 chapters and no details.

Could some one help me please? Does he show the proof in his book at all? What is the page number where he shows the proof?

I'm reading the paper by Matthew Cook for sure. It's just more pictures help me understand things better. I now know pretty well what is the tag system and the cyclic tag system, but still trying to find a way to visualize the equivalence between the tag system and the turing machine. Other resources about this are welcome, too!

Many thanks!

Comment: see [initial conditions rule 110](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/initial-conditions-for-universal-rule-110) tcs.se

Answer (score -2):

Found it:

cyclic tag system to tag system p.669

glider p.678

The pictures are very helpful!